# Как убрать отступы у background-color

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как убрать отступы у background-color

[image: проблема]

```
html

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Desktop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="globalstyle.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="black_div">     
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>

css

* {
    min-width: 1000px;
}

.black_div {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 870px;
    width: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.pink_div {
    background-color: #5036E6;
    margin: auto;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Comment: `body { margin: 0 }` - должно помочь

Comment: помогло, спасибо